# Parralex scroll is not working in Mobile and tabs ( Laravel )

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, tabs, parallax

I am having parallax website in laravel, it working fine in desktop version but when i open the website in **Devices.** Its effect is not working. Zoomed images are shown but **page scrolling is not working.**